# Akka Streams mapConcat Operator on Source Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm reading through the documentation for Akka streams and I came across the mapConcat operator which is like the flatMap (at least on the conceptual level).

Here is a simple example:

```
scala> val src = Source.fromFuture(Future.successful(1 to 10))
src: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive,akka.NotUsed] = Source(SourceShape(FutureSource.out(51943878)))
```

I was expecting that type of the Source is rather:

```
akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[Future[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive],akka.NotUsed]
```

Why is that not the case?

My understanding of the types for each line is as shown below:

```
Source
  .fromFuture(Future.successful(1 to 10)) // Source[Future[Int]]
  .mapConcat(identity) // Source[Int]
  .runForeach(println)
```

But the Source type in the example above is not what I thought it was!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you interested in `Source.fromFuture` or the `mapConcat` operator?

Comment: I have edited my post!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `Source.fromFuture` is:

```
def fromFuture[O](future: Future[O]): Source[O, NotUsed]
```

In your example `O` is of type `scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive` and therefore the return type of `Source.fromFuture` is:

```
Source[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive, NotUsed]
```

Scala [docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Source$.html#fromFuture[O](future:scala.concurrent.Future[O]):akka.stream.javadsl.Source[O,akka.NotUsed])

Here is an example demonstrating the difference between `map` and `mapConcat`:

```
def f: Future[List[Int]] = Future.successful((1 to 5).toList)

def g(l: List[Int]): List[String] = l.map(_.toString * 2)

Source
  .fromFuture(f)
  .mapConcat(g) // emits 5 elements of type Int
  .runForeach(println)

Source
  .fromFuture(f)
  .map(g) // emits one element of type List[Int]
  .runForeach(println)
```

Comment: Then what meaning does this Future.successful(1 to 10) has? I thought I'm emitting a Future(scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive), hence I expect the Future also part of the type signature.

Comment: when using `Source.fromFuture[O]` the stream emits one element of type `O` in case the future is completed with a successful value otherwise the stream fails

Comment: If I understand the mapConcat correctly, it is conceptually similiar to a flatMap. If this is the case, then what is the mapConcat doing actually when there is nothing to flatten? I'm referring to the example above in my post!

Comment: `mapConcat` takes a function which transforms each element into an `Iterable[T]` of output elements. This is then flattened into the stream. That means in following flows you would get  `T` instead of  `Iterable[T]`.

Comment: @sparkr I added a sample for `mapConcat`. Hope it makes it clear.

Comment: Ok so who is unpacking the Future? Is it the fromFuture method or the mapConcat? From your example, I can infer that the fromFuture is the one that unpacks the Future and emits the content inside the Future

Comment: This correct. `mapConcat` does not deal with the `Future`. When it is executed the `Future` was already successfully completed.

Comment: I had a look into the fromFuture implementation and I could see that the Future is evaluated and the result is being pushed further to the next elements in the pipeline, which in this case is the mapConcat method!

Comment: I personally treat mapConcat() as flatMap(). they are doing the same thing. flatten `? :< Traversable` into single element and feed the downstream.